# how to run two functions in onChange - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Iam trying to create a 2 password fields and want to check if the 2 passwords are same and if they are it should enable the signup button.

```js
const [passwordOne, setPasswordOne] = useState("");
const [passwordTwo, setPasswordTwo] = useState("");
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

function checkPassword(input1, input2) {
    if (input1 === input2) {
      setDisabled(false);
      setOutput("");
    } else {
      setDisabled(true);
      setOutput("Passwords do not match");
    }
}

<input
  onChange={(e) => {
    setPasswordOne(e.target.value);    
    checkPassword(passwordOne, passwordTwo)}}
/>
<input
  onChange={(e) => {
    setPasswordTwo(e.target.value);    
    checkPassword(passwordOne, passwordTwo)}}
/>
<button disabled={disabled}>Register</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the value of the latest passwords in your check.

The calls should be:

```
checkPassword(e.target.value, passwordTwo)
// and
checkPassword(passwordOne, e.target.value)
```

Consider simplifying the state:

```
const [passwordOne, setPasswordOne] = useState("");
const [passwordTwo, setPasswordTwo] = useState("");

const isPasswordFilled = passwordOne !== "";
const arePasswordsSame = isPasswordFilled && passwordOne === passwordTwo;

return <>
    <input onChange={(e) => setPasswordOne(e.target.value) />
    <input onChange={(e) => setPasswordTwo(e.target.value) />
    {isPasswordFilled === true && arePasswordsSame === false && <p>Passwords do not match</p>}
    <button disabled={isPasswordFilled === false || arePasswordsSame 
 === false}>Register</button>
</>;
```

Comment: But i did use setPasswordOne(e.target.value) before the checkPassword() to set the value of passwordOne

Comment: Yes, but the value of `passwordOne` doesn't immediately change when you call `setPasswordOne`. It changes in the _next_ render loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [passwordOne, setPasswordOne] = useState("");
const [passwordTwo, setPasswordTwo] = useState("");
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
const [output, setOutput] = useState("");

function checkPassword(input1, input2) {
    if (input1 === input2) {
      setDisabled(false);
      setOutput("");
    } else {
      setDisabled(true);
      setOutput("Passwords do not match");
    }
}

<input
  onChange={(e) => {
    setPasswordOne(e.target.value);    
    checkPassword(e.target.value, passwordTwo)}}
/>
<input
  onChange={(e) => {
    setPasswordTwo(e.target.value);    
    checkPassword(passwordOne, e.target.value)}}
/>
<p>{output}</p>
<button disabled={disabled}>Register</button>
```

You are sending state's value when it didn't set yet.
So, if you can send current parameter, it works well.

Comment: Yes, but useState need a time to set new value. When you sent state value as parameter, it didn't be set yet. So it's sended parameter value is still the old value. As you can see in your own code, when the passwords are equal, the button is still disabled. But when you changed one of passwords after they are equal, button becomes enabled. Because of when you changed password, in onChange method, you send password's old value as parameter not the new value that we wanna set Because id shouldn't set yet. So, this way is better and solves the problem if you see a problem like that.